# Why not all streams are emit value in combineLatest?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a combineLatest operator:

```
this.result$ = combineLatest([
      this.data$.pipe(tap(() => console.log('data'))),
      this.sourceWithImage$.pipe(tap(() => console.log('image'))),
      this.sourceWithFields$.pipe(tap(() => console.log('fields'))),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([data, image, fields]) => {
        return { data, image, fields };
      })
    );
```

Whydo  not all streams emit values? Only data. Stackblitz exmaple by [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-5pq2sk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I have tried to emit default values using startWith, but I dont need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the rest of the code you didn't post:

```js
    this.sourceWithImage$ = this.data$.pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        of().pipe(
          delay(5000),
          map(() => new Date().valueOf())
        )
      )
    );

    this.sourceWithFields$ = this.data$.pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        of().pipe(
          delay(3000),
          map(() => new Date().valueOf())
        )
      )
    );
```

In both `this.sourceWithImage$` and `this.sourceWithFields$`, you have an empty `of()` call in the switchMap. The `of()` operator creates an observable that emits the arguments passed to it. Since you didn't pass any arguments, it creates an observable that completes immediately without emitting any values. This causes the subsequent `delay()` and `map()` operators to have no effect.

To fix this issue, you can modify the `of()` calls to pass a value like this:

```js
this.sourceWithImage$ = this.data$.pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    of(null).pipe( // Pass a value to of()
      delay(5000),
      map(() => new Date().valueOf())
    )
  )
);

this.sourceWithFields$ = this.data$.pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    of(null).pipe( // Pass a value to of()
      delay(3000),
      map(() => new Date().valueOf())
    )
  )
);
```

[Updated Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-gtjckc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Instead of will be fetching image and data from remote server, thank you. I will explore your changes

Comment: Are any issues in my approach? ?

Comment: Could I use forkJoin instead combineLatest?

Comment: Could you check why now I dont get results, I made some changes. Thank you a lot:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-5pq2sk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The error was because you used `sourceData$` before it was defined. Fix here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-5pq2sk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Does not work, check out please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-5pq2sk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

When I clic emit data I dont get data in temaplte

Comment: This is wrong: `takeWhile<boolean>(Boolean, true),`. It should be `  takeWhile<boolean>((value) => value, true), // Replace Boolean with true`

Comment: Any way if form is closed and click emit data I dont get data in template

Comment: Ask a new question. It isn't easy to have this discussion in the comments.

Comment: I asked, could you checj out this/